# Swift convert code to component for use multiple times

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm a Swift newbie and I'm trying to achieve something that feels like it should be easy but my lack of knowledge of Storyboard + Swift + terminology is holding me back!

I'd like to create a horizontal scroller component which achieves the following design goals:

- I can easily add it to any view in my app with a few lines of code
- I can pass in an array of values which configure each of the elements in the scroller
- The scroller elements (cells?) are designed in a .xib file
- I can have multiple instances of the scroller in any view

I've created a simple example scroller which has the following structure:

- ViewController (HorizontalScrollerVC.swift)
- Storyboard (used for creating outlets, constraints and some config)
- A UICollectionViewCell subclass (MyCell.swift)
- A custom xib file where the Class property is set to MyCell.swift (MyCell.xib)

I imagine this component might be used in a ViewController's viewDidLoad() method like this:

```
//**Pseudo code**

let data1 = ["a","b","c"]
let data2 = ["1","2","3"]

let scroller1:MyScroller = ScrollerFromData(data:data1)
scroller1.constraints = somePositioningConstraints
view.add(scroller1)

let scroller2:MyScroller = ScrollerFromDataWithCellType(data:data2,cellType:"MyCell2")
scroller2.constraints = someDifferentPositioningConstraints
view.add(scroller2)
```

Any advice how I can convert my code/structure into something I can use in the way described above would be great.

---

### Code

**HorizontalScrollerVC.swift**

```
import UIKit

class HorizontalScrollerVC: UIViewController {

    // set up some data
    let dataArray = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Indigo", "Violet"]

    // create an outlet to communicate with the collectionView
    @IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "MyCell", bundle: nil)
        self.myCollectionView.registerNib(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
        self.myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.9, green: 0.6, blue: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: CollectionView methods
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCell
        self.configureCell(cell, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }

    func configureCell(cell: MyCell, forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cellTitle = dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.cellTitle.text = cellTitle
    }
}
```

**MyCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MyCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cellTitle: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.95, green: 0.95, blue: 0.95, alpha: 1.0)
        self.cellTitle.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    }
}
```

The **MyCell.xib** is really simple but incase it helps, here's the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15F34" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <view contentMode="scaleToFill" id="iN0-l3-epB" customClass="MyCell" customModule="testola" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="210" height="140"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
            <subviews>
                <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" numberOfLines="4" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="h9Q-Ha-ZnF">
                    <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="118" height="64"/>
                    <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                    <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                    <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                </label>
            </subviews>
            <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
            <constraints>
                <constraint firstItem="h9Q-Ha-ZnF" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="trailingMargin" constant="-76" id="S2o-eE-CYh"/>
                <constraint firstAttribute="bottomMargin" secondItem="h9Q-Ha-ZnF" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="60" id="U0s-fw-Rfv"/>
                <constraint firstItem="h9Q-Ha-ZnF" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" id="rwe-wi-Vff"/>
                <constraint firstItem="h9Q-Ha-ZnF" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="iN0-l3-epB" secondAttribute="topMargin" id="sl1-pT-fj7"/>
            </constraints>
            <freeformSimulatedSizeMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics"/>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="cellTitle" destination="h9Q-Ha-ZnF" id="8E8-HL-BCx"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="195" y="139"/>
        </view>
    </objects>
</document>
```

Here's the **storyboard** xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="10117" systemVersion="15F34" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" initialViewController="49e-Tb-3d3">
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="10085"/>
        <capability name="Constraints to layout margins" minToolsVersion="6.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--First-->
        <scene sceneID="hNz-n2-bh7">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="9pv-A4-QxB" customClass="HorizontalScrollerVC" customModule="testola" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="Ia1-K6-d13"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="4ug-Mw-9AY"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="tsR-hK-woN">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <collectionView clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="scaleToFill" dataMode="prototypes" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ZD4-S1-Vkm">
                                <rect key="frame" x="-4" y="40" width="383" height="150"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="150" id="f2E-DB-ecy"/>
                                </constraints>
                                <collectionViewFlowLayout key="collectionViewLayout" scrollDirection="horizontal" minimumLineSpacing="10" minimumInteritemSpacing="10" id="AYp-cr-c33">
                                    <size key="itemSize" width="210" height="140"/>
                                    <size key="headerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <size key="footerReferenceSize" width="0.0" height="0.0"/>
                                    <inset key="sectionInset" minX="10" minY="0.0" maxX="10" maxY="0.0"/>
                                </collectionViewFlowLayout>
                                <cells>
                                    <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" id="zbW-CO-LP9">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="10" y="-20" width="210" height="140"/>
                                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                                        <view key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center">
                                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="210" height="140"/>
                                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                                            <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                        </view>
                                        <size key="customSize" width="210" height="140"/>
                                    </collectionViewCell>
                                </cells>
                                <connections>
                                    <outlet property="dataSource" destination="9pv-A4-QxB" id="p0g-qN-oUd"/>
                                    <outlet property="delegate" destination="9pv-A4-QxB" id="U7n-os-ldT"/>
                                </connections>
                            </collectionView>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZD4-S1-Vkm" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="Ia1-K6-d13" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="20" id="0Eh-uz-aT3"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="trailingMargin" secondItem="ZD4-S1-Vkm" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="-20" id="2wl-8R-h8o"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="ZD4-S1-Vkm" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="tsR-hK-woN" secondAttribute="leadingMargin" constant="-20" id="XxF-oY-0Bo"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="First" image="first" id="acW-dT-cKf"/>
                    <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina47"/>
                    <connections>
                        <outlet property="myCollectionView" destination="ZD4-S1-Vkm" id="xWz-Uu-tsB"/>
                    </connections>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="W5J-7L-Pyd" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="749.5" y="-320.5"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Second-->
        <scene sceneID="wg7-f3-ORb">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="8rJ-Kc-sve" customClass="SecondViewController" customModule="testola" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <layoutGuides>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="L7p-HK-0SC"/>
                        <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="Djb-ko-YwX"/>
                    </layoutGuides>
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="QS5-Rx-YEW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" text="Second View" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" minimumFontSize="10" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="zEq-FU-wV5">
                                <rect key="frame" x="83" y="313" width="210" height="42"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" name="Helvetica" family="Helvetica" pointSize="36"/>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                            <label opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Loaded by SecondViewController" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="NDk-cv-Gan">
                                <rect key="frame" x="81" y="363" width="215" height="17"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="14"/>
                                <color key="textColor" red="0.0" green="0.0" blue="0.0" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedRGB"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="NDk-cv-Gan" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="zEq-FU-wV5" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" symbolic="YES" id="Day-4N-Vmt"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="NDk-cv-Gan" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="zEq-FU-wV5" secondAttribute="centerX" id="JgO-Fn-dHn"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="zEq-FU-wV5" secondAttribute="centerX" id="qqM-NS-xev"/>
                            <constraint firstAttribute="centerY" secondItem="zEq-FU-wV5" secondAttribute="centerY" id="qzY-Ky-pLD"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                    <tabBarItem key="tabBarItem" title="Second" image="second" id="cPa-gy-q4n"/>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="4Nw-L8-lE0" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="750" y="360"/>
        </scene>
        <!--Tab Bar Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="yl2-sM-qoP">
            <objects>
                <tabBarController id="49e-Tb-3d3" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <nil key="simulatedBottomBarMetrics"/>
                    <simulatedScreenMetrics key="simulatedDestinationMetrics" type="retina47"/>
                    <tabBar key="tabBar" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="W28-zg-YXA">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="975" width="768" height="49"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" flexibleMinY="YES"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" white="0.0" alpha="0.0" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    </tabBar>
                    <connections>
                        <segue destination="9pv-A4-QxB" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="u7Y-xg-7CH"/>
                        <segue destination="8rJ-Kc-sve" kind="relationship" relationship="viewControllers" id="lzU-1b-eKA"/>
                    </connections>
                </tabBarController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="HuB-VB-40B" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="0.0" y="0.0"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <resources>
        <image name="first" width="30" height="30"/>
        <image name="second" width="30" height="30"/>
    </resources>
</document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution which works so I thought I'd post the simple code in case any newbies like me find this post (it's really basic stuff).

The logic is this:

1. create a new Swift project
2. create a custom subclass `new` -> `Cocoa Touch Class` -> `Subclass of`UIViewController`AND check the`Also create XIB file` box
3. Create an IBOutlet on your master view's UIView
4. Create your custom UI in the Xib you created in step 2
5. Add any outlets to your custom xib (I created a label to check it works)
6. In your master VC:

   7. create instances of your subclass (created in step 2) (`let myCustomWidget = CustomViewController(nibName: "CustomViewController", bundle: nil)`
   8. add the instances to the master view controller using `self.addChildViewController(myCustomWidget)`
   9. add the new instance to the view so we can see it `self.masterView.addSubview(myScroller.view)`
   10. send data to the myCustomWidget instance and configure it as needed

---

**A simple example**

What we end up with (A 'master' view with a couple of custom class instances added as subviews):

[image: Screenshot]

**Here's what xcode looks like:**
[image: Xcode screenshot]

**FirstViewController.swift** (The 'master' ViewController)

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    // create this outlet by ctrl+dragging in Storyboard's Assistant view
    @IBOutlet var firstView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // instantiate as many custom VCs as you want (I have a .xib called "ScrollerViewController.xib")
        let myScroller = ScrollerViewController(nibName: "ScrollerViewController", bundle: nil)
        let myScroller2 = ScrollerViewController(nibName: "ScrollerViewController", bundle: nil)

        // add the custom VC to the current VC
        self.addChildViewController(myScroller)
        // add the custom VC's view to the current VC's view (set via IBOutlet above)
        self.firstView.addSubview(myScroller.view)

        // ...do it again for the 2nd custom VC
        self.addChildViewController(myScroller2)
        self.firstView.addSubview(myScroller2.view)

        // move 2 so we can see it (use constraints in production)
        myScroller2.view.frame = CGRectOffset(myScroller2.view.frame, 0, 150);

        // Set up some data
        let dummyData = ["Wotcha!","Hello there"]

        // Pass the data to each instance of the custom VC
        // Note: this has to be done AFTER we've added it to the 'master' view
        myScroller.myTitle.text = dummyData[0]
        myScroller2.myTitle.text = dummyData[1]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

**ScrollerViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ScrollerViewController: UIViewController {

    // create an outlet to show that the passed in data works
    @IBOutlet var myTitle: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have made some custom controls before. What I have done in the past is make a subclass from UIView. Then using IBDesignable I can start writing code for my control and it will show in the Storyboard as you code. Once you are done you simply drag and drop a UIView to your Storyboard and change the class to your custom class that you just made. Since it will be an IBDesignable annotated class you will be able to see it on the screen as your control and not just a plain UIView. Once you place the custom control in the Storyboard, you can also use auto layout to define other stuff such as the width of the control and so on.

You mention passing data to a view controller. I have used something like this on my projects.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let feed = segue.destinationViewController as? FeedTableViewController
            where segue.identifier == "EmbedFeed" {
            feed.yourVariable = [1,2,3]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Xavier. That's a useful tip that I've used for other things. What I don't understand is if I subclass UIView where do I put the code from the ViewController (HorizontalScrollerVC.swift). If the answer is that it stays in the ViewController then I don't understand how I easily create multiple instances of the same subclass with different datasources etc? (I did say I'm a newbie :-) !

Comment: Is your scroller basically a collection view? If so you could subclass a UICollectionView or a UICollectionViewController and you could retain most of your code with the specifics of horizontal scrolling that you want to achieve. Well you could pass the data through prepareForSegue when your view controller is about to be brought to the screen.

Comment: Yes, the example is a really basic CollectionView and I know how to subclass the UICollectionViewController. However, I don't know how to use this custom class in my main ViewController. This must be simple so now searching for that. Thanks to your hint, I've found https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/addChildViewController: which looks promising :-) Thanks.